# How to define & proceed with elements on the webpage using selenium & c#?

Tags: c#

I got the 5 elements on the webpage which i can define by ClassName(Item). All of them consist different digits such 1 , 2 , 15 , 28 etc. Also webpage consist of 5 buttons each belongs to (Item), I can define those buttons by classname too (Button). All of these elements are located in . So my question is how can i find elements which only consist of number "15" & then push the (button) which belongs to this (Item)? Some code will be highly appreciated.

I expect the program will find the items with particular digits & puch the button to proceed with this item.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Lot of info on using element locators here: https://www.guru99.com/locators-in-selenium-ide.html